# Angular: ng-repeat reverse order of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Filter

```
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Data JSON:

```
{
  "results": {
    "100": {
      "numbers": {
        "1": {
          "key": "value"
        },
        "2": {
          "key": "value"
        },
        "3": {
          "key": "value"
        }
      }
    },
    "200": {
      "numbers": {
        "1": {
          "key": "value"
        },
        "2": {
          "key": "value"
        },
        "3": {
          "key": "value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Render:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in results">
  <span ng-repeat="(k1,v1) in v | orderObjectBy:k1:true">{{k1}}</span>
</div>
```

The `orderObjectBy:k1:true` doesn't return the "key" but an array of the keys e.g. `0 1 2`. How can I fix that and reverse the order?

Comment: You can directly make use of reverse filter available in angular.

Comment: @ShankarShastri please see updates in the question. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this

```
ng-repeat='item in items| orderBy:item.key:reverse'
```

or may be

```
ng-repeat='item in items.reverse()'
```

Comment: I'd go with the first option; it's generally discouraged to use a function call as the source of an ngRepeat.

Comment: @ShankarShastri @HarrisWeinstein I tried `ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj | orderBy:key:reverse"` and I get an error `angular.js:13550 Error: [orderBy:notarray]`. Remember, we're attempting this on an object and not an array. If I add `toArray:true` as in `ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj | toArray:true | orderBy:key:reverse"`, I get an error: `TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object`. Any ideas?

Comment: @ShankarShastri Updated my question.

Comment: please update proper JSON.You can test your JSON here.

http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @ShankarShastri after more research and thinking, updated the question again. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In my bikes CMS ( where bikes are obj) I wanted to reverse the bikes list

That's the way I  reversed :

```
<tr ng-repeat="bike in bikes | orderBy: '-' ">
```

I hope that helps somebody :D